# Forward POST request to an other url with Silex?

Tags: php, silex

I have a search form with some input-fields. The form is located at `/search/` and is transferred via POST.
If the form is fired i want to forward the user to `/search/{one_parameter_from_form}`. The parameter should be encoded and cleaned for use in urls.

I tried the following:

```
$app->post('/search', 
    function (Request $request) use($app)
    {
        return $app->redirect('/search/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $request->get('q')));
    });
```

But here i have to "clean" the request-parameter myself and i cant access all other request-parameters in the redirected controller.

1) How can i access all POST-parameters in the forward?

2) How can i get a clean request-url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Symfony user, but it appears as though you can create a subrequest and execute it as if it were a forward.

[Cookbook entry](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html)

Snippet:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$subRequest = Request::create('/');
$response = $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);
```

Comment: If i will do a sub-request, i am not able to forward the user to the url ```/search/param```. The url will be only ```/search```

Comment: You're generally not allowed to redirect a POST request as per the HTTP standard. THere is a status 307, but this isn't going to be useful. You can use a subrequest and THEN redirect, which will give you basically the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$app->redirect('/', 303);`. Status code of 303 causes browser to try GET for redirect url instead of POST.